# How can I bind Ctrl + L to "Create Link" in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

While composing a message in Gmail is there a way to create a keyboard shortcut that will create a new link by pressing the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> combination?

When I want to create a link in sites like Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange sites, I automatically hit the keys for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> which brings up the hyperlink helper.

Can the same be enabled for emailing in Gmail?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Google has heard you and there is now a hyperlink shortcut in Gmail:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> for Mac users)

It works only if the cursor is in the *message* field, not in the *To*, *Cc*, *Bcc* or *Subject* ones. And, in Chrome on Mac, it works even when the shortcuts are disabled.

See [here](http://lifehacker.com/5881208/add-hyperlinks-to-gmail-messages-with-a-keyboard-shortcut).

This shortcut is not yet documented in the official [Gmail keyboard shortcuts list](http://lifehacker.com/5881208/add-hyperlinks-to-gmail-messages-with-a-keyboard-shortcut), so don't look for it there.

Comment: Note that it's still not documented in the official [Gmail keyboard shortcuts list](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=6594), so don't look for it there.

Comment: For Mac users, use **Cmd** + **K**. Observation: the cursor must be in the _message_ field, not _To_, _Cc_, _Bcc_ or _Subject_.

Comment: And it seems to be working even when the shortcuts are disabled. In Chrome, on Mac at list.

Comment: @Alex - feel free to add your comments to my answer. they are certainly relevant.

Comment: you can also press "?" (shift + /)  for a list of keyboard shortcuts

Comment: Cool~ I found this shortcut for Google docs recently, but didn't realize it works in gmail, too!

Answer (score 4):

While there is a "Custom keyboard shortcuts" Lab for Gmail which will let you redefine the [existing keyboard shortcuts](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=6594), there doesn't appear to be one for creating a link. (You can send them [feedback](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/request.py?contact_type=labs&selected=custom_keyboard) about that, of course.)