# Is there a hyperlink shortcut in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, links, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I bind Ctrl + L to “Create Link” in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17378/how-can-i-bind-ctrl-l-to-create-link-in-gmail)

I include a lot of hyperlinks in my emails. But highlighting, mouse-ing over and then clicking the "paperclip" link icon (and then navigating the box that opens after that) is a chore.

In most mail clients I can highlight and hit CTRL-K to include a hyperlink. According to [this list of Gmail shortcuts](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=6594), there is no hyperlink shortcut in Gmail.

Is this true? What can I do to make Gmail hyperlinking more user-friendly?

Comment: Thanks for finding that. But still, my question appears unanswered. Is sending Google feedback all I can do?

Comment: Either Googleback or finding a Monkeyscript